# Save installation path to INI file

Tags: inno-setup

I got the mission to save the actual installation path into an INI file (to a certain key).
During installation, the user get a default folder to install the app, but he can change it in run-time (in the wizard).
How to catch the final folder path he decided about, and place it into my INI file?

Thank you!

Comment: Note that most applications can discover the path to themselves while they're running using library/API calls, so there's no need to do this if it's for the use of the app itself.  Writing the location to a file is only useful if it's required by some other app that can't figure it out any other way.

Comment: @Miral if you (happen to) install Javafx based applications (its native packaged installers on windows use inno setup), this could be useful (because finding the location of a jar file from within a running Java program is a bit hard)

Comment: @BjarneBoström There are [several solutions to that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the value using an `[Ini]` entry and the `{app}` constant.

```
[INI]
Filename: "MyProg.ini"; Section: "InstallSettings"; Key: "InstallPath"; String: "{app}"
```

Note that as [Gavin pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608096/save-installation-path-to-ini-file#comment32672539_21608096), an application can determine it's own path so this shouldn;t normally be needed unless external applications require it in which case, a [registry](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_registrysection.htm) entry is a lot easier to find:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\My Company\My Program\Settings"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "InstallPath"; ValueData: "{app}"
```

(`[Ini]` answer curtosy of [TLama's deleted post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21608143/588306).)